# Average two rows in Python while ignoring NaN

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, average, mean

I have a two-dimensional array of data. I need to average every two rows, and return the average with an array half of the height. I also need to ignore all NaN values for averaging purposes. For example:

```
>>> x = numpy.array([[ 1,  nan,  3,  4,  5],
... [ 6,  7,  8,  9, nan],
... [11, 12, 13, 14, nan],
... [16, nan, 18, 19, nan]])
```

And the function would need to return:

```
>>> x
array([[3.5,  7,  5.5,  6.5,  5],
[13.5, 12, 15.5, 16.5, nan]])
```

Comment: `numpy` has `masked array`, and i'd think you can specify the np.nan being the mask, then apply the averaging operation.

Comment: +1: question is kind of localized, but at least it's clear and concise with expected input and output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
numpy.ma.average(numpy.ma.masked_invalid(x).reshape(-1, 2, x.shape[-1]), 1)
```

For me it returns

```py
masked_array(data =
 [[3.5 7.0 5.5 6.5 5.0]
 [13.5 12.0 15.5 16.5 --]],
             mask =
 [[False False False False False]
 [False False False False  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Comment: Props to yosukesabai for suggesting `masked_array`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much. Just started learning Python this summer, still a long way to go!

Comment: hmmm, i am getting `array([[  3.5,   nan,   5.5,   6.5,   nan],
       [ 13.5,   nan,  15.5,  16.5,   nan]])`, and not sure what's wrong

Comment: Added my output to the answer. I don't know why you would be getting different output. I'm using python 2.6 with numpy 1.3.0.

Comment: Any idea why using numpy.savetxt it saves the -- values as zeros?

Comment: `numpy.savetxt` doesn't seem to work on masked arrays. Convert back to a normal array with explicit `NaN` values with `x.filled(numpy.NaN)`, then pass it to `numpy.savetxt`.